# Upside down Orientation issue in iOS6

Tags: objective-c, ios6, uiinterfaceorientation

I am creating a sample empty application and added UIViewController class,

Below is the code in the App delgate

```
TestViewController* viewController  = [[TestViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TestViewController" bundle:nil];

UINavigationController* navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController];

[self.window setRootViewController:navController];
```

Now i am rotating the App but in the UPsidedown Orientation Navigation bar is not Rotating I am attaching a screen shot

[image]

Then Added a the Below Method in App delegate

```
- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window{


    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}
```

And in the Class i have added following methods

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return (UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll);
}
```

In the Summary i have activated all the orientations can any One tell me the Solution for it

Answer (score 1):

1) just You created a category for UINavigationController class and I defined these methods

**In CustomViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CustomViewController : UINavigationController

@end
```

**In CustomViewController.m**

```
#import "CustomViewController.h"

@interface CustomViewController ()

@end

@implementation CustomViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(BOOL) shouldAutorotate{
    return YES;
}

-(NSUInteger) supportedInterfaceOrientations{

    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}
```

**And AppDelgate.m file**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

     self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];

    CustomViewController *navController = [[CustomViewController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    self.window.rootViewController = navController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

2) And check Orientation In Target 
[image]

3) Change the class from **UINavigationController** to the **CustomViewController** in my XIB in IB

4) Reset the Simulator and run the code, I think your problem will be solve.

Comment: Your solution works Deepesh(I subclass to UINavigationController) what is the problem if we implement in the Way i implemented

Comment: I am not understand your reply

Comment: @Deepesh sir, http://media.salemwebnetwork.com/ecards/holidays/Teachers_WorkTalent.jpg

Comment: This works, instead of an ecard, here is an upvote from me!  One additional thing I had to do for my project is change the class from navigationcontroller to the custom class in my XIB in IB.  Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to use

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
return TRUE;
}
```

instead of shouldAutorotate

Comment: Hi Fonix, I am deploying the App in iOS6 i feel from iOS6 we have diffrent methods, I implemented the above method too but same result.

Comment: obvious question, but did you check if your supported interface orientations are set correctly in your project settings and the plist

Comment: Yes I did each and every point discussed here i checked in the Plist also still not getting, It is just sample code i am choosing Empty Template,

Answer (score 0):

Upside Down button to ON in `Supported interface orientations` on Xcode

http://www.appcoda.com/ios-game-tutorial-maze-part-1/

Answer (score 0):

`TestViewController* viewController  = [[TestViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TestViewController" bundle:nil];

[self.window setRootViewController:viewController];`

remove the navigatioan bar from appdelegate and then check